# Can't login to Ubuntu installed on VirtualBox

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on VirtualBox 5.0. The installation was successful, however the moment i enter the password, the home screen flashes and takes me back to login screen. I have seen various other threads, but nothing works for me.

Comment: try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password